# STAB in Pokémon Sun & Moon

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

The STAB mechanic is something I'm not sure it was already in the previous pokemon series (except pokemon GO), but is there a STAB in Pokémon Sun and Moon?

Comment: [`The same-type attack bonus was introduced in Generation I and has remained unchanged since.`](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Same-type_attack_bonus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there has always been Same Type Attack Bonus in Pokémon games, and Sun & Moon are no exception. It is still a 50% boost.

Comment: There's also an NPC at Trainer School who mentions STAB: "*if your Pokémon uses a move of the same type as itself, its attack power increases*", or something similar.